# Multiple request with php

Tags: php, json

I have sportsbook api and i fetch the event id's at once. But i have to get game odds also,and this info requries get request to another json for each game.

Event id's come from https://api.b365api.com/v1/bwin/prematch?sport_id=4&token=blabalba

There is a 100 event id's, and when i want to access each game odds ı have to request to like

https://api.b365api.com/v1/bwin/event?token=blabalba&event_id=206447553

I write code and use in foreach but it's not working.

```
$all = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.b365api.com/v1/bwin/prematch?sport_id=4&token=184826-Nd2LtOvW49KiP6"));
$eventIds = array(); 
$eventIdsCount;

$bingo = 0;
$eventid;

foreach ($all->results as $events) {
$eventid = $events->Id;
//echo $eventid;
//echo "||";

$eventjson = file_get_contents("https://api.b365api.com/v1/bwin/event?token=184826-Nd2LtOvW49KiP6&event_id=$eventid");

$data = json_decode($eventjson, true);

$price = $data['results'][0]['optionMarkets'][0]['options'][0]['price']['odds'];
$pricex = $data['results'][0]['optionMarkets'][0]['options'][1]['price']['odds'];
$price2 = $data['results'][0]['optionMarkets'][0]['options'][2]['price']['odds'];

echo "1: " . $price . "//";

echo "X: " . $pricex . "//";

echo "2: " . $price2 . "//";

echo "------";

}
```

What's the best practice for request 100 json same time ?